# ASP.NET 5 - Getting a 404 error, but when I dig in with the console on chrome, I see it is looking in an old directory

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, asp.net-core, browser-cache

I'm referencing these files in my index.html:

```
<link href="wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="wwwroot/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="wwwroot/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="wwwroot/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="wwwroot/app/controllers/home.controller.js"></script>
```

But when I build the project with IIS Express in visual studio, I get a 404 error for each one. When I look at the console and resources tabs in Chrome to see where it's trying to pull the files from, I see that the directory is an old one from a previous, similar project.

I've tried clearing my cache in several different ways and deleting the old project altogether, but nothing is working...

Answer (score 2):

`wwwroot` is the root WWW directory. You should remove these path prefixes from your script's and css's links.

```
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/controllers/home.controller.js"></script>
```